# How can I save PVC card details directly to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, cardreader

I am trying to build an Attendence software where in user swaps the card and his attendence is marked. Right now I am opening a WINFORM and take card's number on a textbox and save it, and its works fine. But according to client user will not open any WINFORM or anything. He/She comes and swipes the card and it should mark his/hers attendence. 
So is there any way I can take card's data and save it.
My DB is SQL SERVER 2012.

EDITED:

How ever right now I am taking cards number on a textbox and on textchange event I save it. But for that one has to open an application everytime, and thats what is not needed as maximum  employees whose attendance will be marked are least tech-savvy.
SO max they can do its just swipe the card. And for that I need assistance.
I have googled and found out about API. Can building an API would solve the problem.

Comment: What kind of card reader/hardware will you be using? Have you looked for their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may or may not be running the right card of card scanner. I.e., if your card scanner just simulates keystrokes, you really need some kind of "app" to to be the context of those keystrokes.

If you have the right kind of scanner, there will be an API that will be appropriate for using without an "active app" to capture the keystrokes.

If you are stuck with using the keystroke based reader, probably about all you can do is what you are doing now, but make your app "invisible" to the user, e.g., 0% opacity, etc. but if the user can manipulate the machine to close you invisible app, etc. you will be in a losing battle.

Comment: -Yes thats what I thought, can you suggest any such Hardware.

Comment: Sorry, don't buy these personally (write software for them though). Any qualified vendor should be able to answer your tech questions, maybe you can get credit if you buy the right scanner from the same vendor.

Comment: Whats that hardware called, I mean any particular type(not the manufacturer) that I should ask for??

Comment: Search for PVC card reader, or mag strip reader -- you will find them. You will have to look at them individually to determine if the are keyboard players or API based (or dual mode).